# how to extract all symbols that will be generated using clang?

Tags: c++, clang

If I compile a translation unit I'm able to extract all the symbol names using `objdump` or `nm`. 
As I'm not interested in the generated artefact itself, I'd like to avoid compilation if possible.

Is there a way to use clang-tooling to extract the symbols / mangled function name?

Comment: Mangled symbols and names are a product of the compilation process.

Comment: true, but you can instrument eg. clang-query to get all function declarations. However I'm not sure how to use clang's mangler to compute the mangled name of those function declarations